# Prove graph does not have a bridge

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $H$ be a connected graph and it contains two spanning trees $A, B$. $A, B$ do not share any edges with each other (H may contain edges in neither A or B). Show $H$ does not have a bridge.

For contradiction suppose edge $e$ is a bridge and in $H$ and let $e = uv$ so Now suppose there are 2 connected components of $H - e$: $G_1, G_2$ such that $u$ is in $G_1$ and $v$ is in $G_2$.

However, notice that if $e$ is not in $A$ or if $e$ is not in $B$ then it is not possible for either of the trees to cover one of $\{u, v\}$ vertices so $e$ must be in both $A, B$. Contradiction.

Is this correct justification?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: No good reason as far as I can see, so (+1).

Comment: As a minor correction, you should say: Now suppose there are $2$ connected components $G_1, G_2$ of $H-e$ . . .

Comment: @quasi, thanks, I'll do that. Is everything else seeming correct?

Comment: I guess the point that should be made is that, since trees are _connected_, $A$ can't have points of both $G_1$ and $G_2$ unless $e\in A$. Similarly for $B$. Other than making that point, the argument looks good.

Comment: Your proof is fine. I do want to mention though that you can also rephrase it to be in two steps 1) If $S$ is a spanning tree of $H$, $S$ must contain every bridge of $H$ 2) If there exists disjoint spanning trees $A$ and $B$ of $H$, then $H$ has no bridges.

Comment: @YacoubKureh, thanks mate, noted down!